# PHP string skips to next line after inserted variable?

Tags: php, string, email, variables, line

I'm using the php mail function and trying to insert variables into my email messages.
Here is some sample code that's similar to what I'm doing

```
<?php
$name = "franklin";
$message = "blah blah blah".$name.".";
?>
```

$name is coming from a csv file.

The problem is that the period after $name is being bumped to the next line, so the message looks like this:

```
blah blah blah franklin
.  <--period is here
```

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: What code do you use to send an e-mail?

Comment: Need to read more codes from you before we can figure out what's going on. In your codes, you just stated 2 variables.

Comment: if you say that the $name variable comes from an external file maybe the way you are reading it is causing a new line to be added to the value.. you check what happens if you use trim on that variable..

Comment: Maybe $name contains a \n from the csv file.

Comment: Add `var_dump($name);` to your code to see what comes out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try trim function like this:

```
$message = "blah blah blah". trim($name) . ".";
```

Your variable `$name` might have `EOL` as the last character thus bumping period after that to next line.

Comment: Thank you so much! trim function worked, didn't realize "end of line" is stored as a character.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
str_replace("\n", "", $name);
```

or

```
trim($name);
```

Comment: trim is more suitable, since it's OS-independant. \n is Unix-specific.